# Best way to configure Webpack4 and @polkadot dependencies in a webworker?

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-front-end

I am in the process of updating a react-app from polkadot.js api: 6.9.2 -> 7.12.1. Following some advice in the docs: https://polkadot.js.org/docs/usage/FAQ/, I updated my customize-cra application with some babel plugins and webpack loaders. I am running `import { u8aToHex } from '@polkadot/util'` in a web worker. I am wondering if something is wrong with my configuration.

After upgrading and adding the babel plugins and webpack loaders, I hit the following error. The code does not hit this issue in polkadot 6.9.2.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined
getAbsoluteUrl  @   packageInfo.js:8
../../node_modules/@polkadot/x-global/packageInfo.js    @   packageInfo.js:24
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:167
(anonymous) @   index.js:1
../../node_modules/@polkadot/x-global/index.js  @   index.js:17
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:167
../../node_modules/@polkadot/x-textdecoder/browser.js   @   browser.js:1
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:167
../../node_modules/@polkadot/util/detectOther.js    @   detectOther.js:1
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:167
../../node_modules/@polkadot/util/detectPackage.js  @   detectPackage.js:1
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:167
../../node_modules/@polkadot/util/index.js  @   index.js:1
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:167
```

Babel plugins and webpack loaders:

```
  removeBuiltInBabelConfig,
  ...addBabelPresets(
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
    ['@babel/preset-react', { development: false, runtime: 'automatic' }],
    ['@babel/preset-env', { loose: true, modules: 'commonjs', targets: { browsers: '>0.25% and last 2 versions and not ie 11 and not OperaMini all', node: '12' } }]
  ),
  addBabelPlugin('@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator'),
  addBabelPlugin('@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator'),
  addBabelPlugin('@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining'),
  addBabelPlugin(['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime', { "useESModules": false }]),
  addBabelPlugin('@babel/plugin-syntax-bigint'),
  addBabelPlugin('@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx'),
  addBabelPlugin('@babel/plugin-syntax-top-level-await'),
  addBabelPlugin('babel-plugin-styled-components'),
  addBabelPlugin(['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { "loose": true }]),
  addBabelPlugin(['@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods', { "loose": true }]),
  addBabelPlugin(['@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object', { "loose": true }]),
  addExternalBabelPlugin(['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { "loose": true }]),
  addExternalBabelPlugin(['@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods', { "loose": true }]),
  addExternalBabelPlugin(['@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object', { "loose": true }]),

-----

config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: require.resolve('@open-wc/webpack-import-meta-loader'),
    })
```

Comment: I faced a similar issue but I do not remember if it was the one you mention. I added `import "@polkadot/api-augment"` where the API was used but seems irrelevant to `window not defined`. Can you please provide some more details or maybe a repo that I can have a look at the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error above stems from the usage of `import.meta.url`.

WP4 does not have support for this (unlike WP5), so an extra import loader is needed as per the polkadot-js docs https://polkadot.js.org/docs/usage/FAQ#on-webpack-4-i-have-a-parse-error-on-importmetaurl mentioned in your post.

The error is caused by this loader inside a webworker.

The loader creates a `getAbsoluteUrl` function that emulates the `import.meta.url` and this function itself refers to `window.location`. Since webworkers doesn't have the `window` object, only making `self` available, this process fails with the above error.

There doesn't seem to be a workaround for this, apart from upgrading to WP5 or bypassing it altogether.

Some additional ideas may be gleamed from looking at the actual injected loader support code, specifically https://github.com/polkadot-js/common/issues/1435#issuecomment-1072052502